# Get Specific column from Json Request using SendGrid APIs

Tags: python, json, api, email, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid APIs to fetch my emails status.

```
https://api.sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.json?api_user=your_sendgrid_username&api_key=your_sendgrid_password&date=1
```

I have written this python code to get the requested data...

```
import requests

SG_USERNAME = 'abc'
SG_PASSWORD = 'abc'
SG_URL = "https://sendgrid.com/api"

if __name__ == '__main__':
     block_url = "{}/bounces.get.json?api_user=abc&api_key=abc".format(
        SG_URL, SG_USERNAME, SG_PASSWORD)
     res = requests.get(block_url)
     # Example output:
     # [{u'status': u'4.0.0', u'reason': u'Unable to resolve MX host example.com: noerror', u'email': u'test@example.com'}]
     print block_url
     print res.json()
```

The Request Return the request like this... but i have to extract all returns email from it only. How would i do this using above python code.

```
     [
{
"status": "5.1.1",
"reason": "550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 qb4si4640453igb.5 - gsmtp ",
"email": "taqi.hass@cogilent.com"
},
{
"status": "5.1.1",
"reason": "550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 l81si30386677iod.48 - gsmtp ",
"email": "taqi.offfffffffffffff@gmail.com"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.json` is a list of dict. You can then use list comprehension to select all the "email" of each dict:

```
>>> [d["email"] for d in res.json()]
['taqi.hass@cogilent.com', 'taqi.offfffffffffffff@gmail.com']
```

Comment: what if i have to get a single email request let suppose i have to check if the taqi.offfffffff@gmail.com is present in the response then how would i transverse

Comment: just test `taqi.offfff@gmail.com in  [d["email"] for d in res.json()]`